# Display specific Array for specific item when click on it using Recyclerview "ItemClickListener"

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview

I Have a problem with my Adapter, First I want to display a different Array of data for every item in RecyclerView when clicking on it like this...

```
        Item 1 "display" Array one 
        Item 2 "display" Array two
```

And so on... My data will be display in ViewPager on Activity, so I want to pass the data from the RecyclerView Adapter that have the items to the Activity that will display the data "The Activity has Viewpager that will get the data"

So that's what I tried before but it is just open the activity and not display the data.

First Her's **My RecyclerView Adapter** that has the **items And the data**

**RecyclerViewItems.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewQuran extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewQuran.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<QuranListDetail> item;

    /* My data "Arrays" */
// first Array for First item
public static int[] mImageIds = new int[]
        {
                R.drawable.test_heart, R.drawable.test_home,
                R.drawable.test_image, R.drawable.test_image, R.drawable.test_video,
        };
// second Array for second item
public static int[] mImageIds2 = new int[]
        {
                R.drawable.nabawe_image_full, R.drawable.nabawe_image_full,
                R.drawable.nabawe_image_full, R.drawable.nabawe_image_full, R.drawable.nabawe_image_full,
        };

public RecyclerViewQuran(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<QuranListDetail> items) {
    this.item = items;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewQuran.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_quran, viewGroup, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewQuran.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemTitle.setText(item.get(position).getSurahName());
    holder.itemDetail.setText(item.get(position).getSurahDetail());
    holder.itemNumber.setText(item.get(position).getSurahNumber());

    // click listener to open new activity "shurah"
    holder.itemClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            // Array 1
            if (position == 0) {
                int image = mImageIds[position];
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuranSurahDisplay.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageDisplay", image);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            // Array 2
            else if (position == 1) {
                int image = mImageIds2[position];
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuranSurahDisplay.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageDisplay", image);
                context.startActivity(intent);}
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return item.size();

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView itemTitle;
    private TextView itemDetail;
    private TextView itemNumber;
    private View itemClick;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        itemTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.surah_name);
        itemDetail = view.findViewById(R.id.surah_detail);
        itemNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.surah_number);
        itemClick = view.findViewById(R.id.item_click);
    }
}
```

.

**Second my ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerSurahAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private int[] mImageIds;

public ViewPagerSurahAdapter(Context context, int[] mImageIds) {
    mContext = context;
    this.mImageIds = mImageIds;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NotNull View view, @NotNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@NotNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // PhotoView to zoom in the image "Instaded of ImageView"
    PhotoView imageView = new PhotoView (mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    container.addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, @NotNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((ImageView) object);
   }
}
```

**Third My Activity that will display the data in the ViewPager, My problem here I don't know how to pass the data in the ViewPager, Her's what I did.**

```
public class QuranSurahDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_surah);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("imageDisplay")) {
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager_quran_fateha);
        int[] url = intent.getIntArrayExtra("imageDisplay");
        //ViewPager
        ViewPagerSurahAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerSurahAdapter(this,url);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
       }

   }
}
```

**If you have any questions u can write it in the comments and I will be explaining to you.**